# Custom path for 1 Mongodb Database

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I'm developing tool (in Java) that works with files on external HDD.  According to my idea program and DB should store on external drive and work on any windows PC.

Could I somehow locate my mongodb database on this external HDD?

**UPD.**
To connect to DB I do:

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
database = mongoClient.getDatabase("baseName");
```

How could I set path to DB files?

Comment: I don't know if I really understand what your aim is. Could you be more elaborate on the particular use case?

Answer (score 0):

Since the paths change from one computer to another it will be hard to detect your database, also the case for multiple external hardrives connected to a computer would make this even worse.

My suggestion is this: Use a **file chooser** (`JFileChooser` in java) with the proper error messages in case the user selects the wrong files, that way you can always select your database and use it from any computer.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell how to connect to DB on custom path?
Now I do:

this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
            this.database = mongoClient.getDatabase("baseName");

Comment: The file Chooser will take care of this for you, read the docs on how to use a JFileChooser, here's a link to the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html   and please accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with JFileChooser:) I don't know how to connect to mongo DB that located by path that returns JFileChooser. I'll be really happy if you can help with this.

Comment: First you'll need to make a User interface and add the JFileChooser to it, second you'll need to set the file path to database in your code to the path that the JFileChooser provides, you don't have to provide any path for the database because the Chooser takes care of it for you, after that you'll need to make a connection using JDBC with a Mongodb driver(i hope you're fimiliar with this because this is completely different and a long issue from the one we're facing here)...and voila you'll find yourself connected to the database using any computer that has Java installed.